# I was unable to style the active route in React using react-router

Tags: css, reactjs

I intend to style the active route in React using react-router. I am using NavLink to do so. Please see the below code:

COMPONENT.JS

```
import React from 'react';
import classes from './navBar.module.css';
import {NavLink} from 'react-router-dom'

const NavBar = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className={classes.navBarStyle}>
            <p className={classes.navBarTitle}>EMPOYEE DATABASE</p>
            <nav className={classes.nav}>
               <ul className = {classes.navUl}>
                   <li><NavLink to="/" exact>HOME</NavLink></li>
                   <li><NavLink to="/addEmployee">ADD</NavLink></li>
               </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    )
}

export default NavBar;
```

COMPONENT.module.css

```
.nav {
    height: 100%;   
}

.navUl {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
}

.navUl li {
    height: 100%;
}

.navUl li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 20px;
}


.navUl li a:hover{
    background-color: rgb(235, 91, 25);
}

/* STYLING THE ACTIVE ROUTE HERE */
.navUl li a.active {
    background-color: rgb(119, 47, 14);
    border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}
```

I can see the `class = "active"` getting embedded inside the anchor tag when a particular route is selected.

[image]

Hence I intend styled with `a.active`, but it wasn't getting styled as specified in css file. I don't see any specifity issues in CSS and even the styles doesn't get appeared in the chrome developer tools. Irony is `a:hover` is working but `a.active` isn't. Where am I going wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may use `activeStyle` class in your `<NavLink/>` Tag:-

```
import React from 'react';
import classes from './navBar.module.css';
import {NavLink} from 'react-router-dom'

const NavBar = (props) => {
   const style = {
        color: 'black',
        fontWeight: 'bold'
    }
    return (
        <div className={classes.navBarStyle}>
            <p className={classes.navBarTitle}>EMPOYEE DATABASE</p>
            <nav className={classes.nav}>
               <ul className = {classes.navUl}>
                   <li><NavLink activeStyle={style} to="/" exact>HOME</NavLink> 
                   </li>
                <li><NavLink activeStyle={style} to="/addEmployee" >ADD</NavLink></li>
               </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    )
}

export default NavBar;
```

Comment: It's working fine as the added styles will be inline. Thank you so much. But still pondering why isn't it working in the first place as the class="active" get's added withing anchor tag.

Answer (score 15):

The reason it doesn't work is because you're using CSS Modules and it mangles the names of your classes to scope it locally to your JSX file. Your class `.active` isn't called `.active` anymore after it compiles. It will be prefixed and suffixed to something like `.navUl_active__10Mm9` (as an example). Then, your JSX won't be able to pick up that class as it's still looking for `.active`. You can fix it by using an imported class as the `activeClassName`.

You can keep your CSS the same:

```
.navUl li a.active {
   background-color: rgb(119, 47, 14);
   border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}
```

Import your CSS the same way:

```
import classes from './navBar.module.css';
```

Add the imported style:

```
<li><NavLink activeClassName={classes.active} to="/" exact>HOME</NavLink></li>
<li><NavLink activeClassName={classes.active} to="/addEmployee">ADD</NavLink></li>
```

Here, your JSX will use whatever the CSS class compiles down to.

Comment: **activeClassName** is removed per React Router v6. If you are using React Router v6 and up use @Chilaxathor 's answer like this:

`className={(isActive) => (isActive ? classes.active : "")}`

Answer (score 6):

I think I found a bit better approach, using `:global`.
Class `active` is default react router active link class.

```
// AppNav.module.scss
.AppNavLink {
  text-decoration : none;

  &:global.active {
    border : 1px solid deeppink;
  }
}
```

Thanks to this, you don't have to add any extra js/html code anywhere.

Comment: Global selector is must-have in case of css-modules. Above example does the trick, thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can use activeClassName like this:

```
<NavLink to="/faq" activeClassName="navUl__active">
```

Hence it will be easier to style it in the CSS file. If you want `className` to stay the same, then you probably should remove `a` from the CSS selector:

```
.navUl li .active {
   background-color: rgb(119, 47, 14);
   border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}
```

I suspect that specifying both element and class can break CSS here. You never know...

Answer (score 3):

**React Router v6:**

Source: [Active NavLink Classes with React Router](https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/active-navlink-classes-with-react-router)

Now you can use the `className` property which now accepts a function and passes an `isActive` boolean property, like this:

```
<NavLink
  to="users"
  className={({ isActive }) => (isActive ? 'active' : 'inactive')}
>
  Users
</NavLink>
```

You can also add multiple classes too, since **v6** is out:

```
<NavLink
  to="users"
  className={({ isActive }) =>
    isActive ? 'bg-green-500 font-bold' : 'bg-red-500 font-thin'
  }
>
  Users
</NavLink>
```

Demo: [Active NavLink Classes with React Router](https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/active-navlink-classes-with-react-router)

Comment: hyperlinks are broken. I believe they are referring to https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/active-navlink-inline-styles-with-react-router

Answer (score 0):

I am using SASS and I used global.

Below is example in SASS

```
.navItem {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  column-gap: 1.3rem;

  .navLink {
    display: flex;
    column-gap: 1.3rem;
    font-family: "Barlow Condensed", sans-serif;

    .pageNumber {
      font-weight: 700;
    }

    .pageName {
      font-weight: 400;
    }

    &:global.active {
      background-color: red;
      color: red;
      font-weight: bold;
      border: 1px solid;
    }
  }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).