# NavLink active styling does not work | React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I applied `activeClassName` to `<NavLink>` but it wouldn't style it when it's on the page. What would happen instead is when the link is clicked on it styles the link but it reverts back when click is released. Here's a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z88dP.png). I also tried `activeStyle` but same thing. Here's my code.

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {
    Route,
    NavLink,
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Switch
} from 'react-router-dom';

import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import Users from './Users';
import Contact from './Contact';
import Notfound from './Notfound';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

const routing = (
    <Router>
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <NavLink exact activeClassName="active" to="/">Home</NavLink>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <NavLink activeClassName="active" to="/users">Users</NavLink>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <NavLink activeClassName="active" to="/contact">Contact</NavLink>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
                <Route path="/users" component={Users} />
                <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
                <Route component={Notfound} />
            </Switch>
        </div>
    </Router>
)

ReactDOM.render(routing, document.getElementById('root'));
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

index.css

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2rem;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}


/* a, a:hover {
  color: black;
} */

a.active {
  color: red;
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "routing",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.3.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

This is the [tutorial](https://codeburst.io/getting-started-with-react-router-5c978f70df91) that I was following. I know this is a duplicate question but none of the answers were able to help.

Browsers tested on:

- Firefox Developer Edition 73.0b12 (64-bit)
- Google Chrome 79.0.3945.130 (Official Build)(64-bit)

React Version: ^16.12.0

React Router Version: ^5.1.2

[Screenshot of DevTools Component for active NavLink](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dn0R3.png)

[Screenshot of DevTools Component for Link child](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgmCG.png)

Last edit: Alright guys thanks for the responses. None have been helpful so I'm going to leave this feature and make a workaround.

Comment: If you inspect the link in dev tools, do you see the active class being applied and then immediately removed?

Comment: It works perfectly fine for me. Are there any other errors you are getting?

Comment: Jeremy, no the active class doesn't get applied at all. sina_r, no other errors.

Answer (score 0):

The following Code works for me:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {
  Route,
  NavLink,
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch
} from 'react-router-dom';

import './index.css';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';


class App extends React.Component {
render() { 
    return (        
<Router>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <NavLink exact activeClassName="active" to="/">Home</NavLink>
            </li>
            <li>
                <NavLink activeClassName="active" to="/users">Users</NavLink>
            </li>
            <li>
                <NavLink activeClassName="active" to="/contact">Contact</NavLink>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </div>
</Router>

     );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Index.css

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2rem;
  font-family: sans-serif;
```

}

```
/* a, a:hover {
  color: black;
} */

a.active {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: 1. You took out the routes so it wouldn't really work.
2. It didn't work after adding the routes back in.

Comment: It works for me even with the routes in it. I took it out simply for better overview of the code. Maybe you can share a link to a live editor so I can see what the problem is on your side.

Comment: It actually worked on the sandbox. https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-haibt-k2cvv The code on there is the same as the code I have on my local editor except for test files. I'll add the package.json file in the question. If there's anything wrong in there.

Comment: I checked the package.json file and it seems to be all good. I tried it for me and again it worked. If the fiddle worked maybe something wrong with how you run your app with your local editor?

Comment: I have the app open in VS Code. I'm running it with `npm start` nothing else.

Comment: Can you add a Screenshot of your devtool Component "Link" that is active. Does the className come up as undefined?

Comment: Edited it in the question at the end. No it doesn't come up as undefined.

Comment: Sorry I did not mean the "NavLink" but the Children "Link" of the Component that is active that moment. It should have a className: "active". Can you check and add that screenshot

Comment: Alright I've edited that in as well. It has a className of "undefined".

Comment: the className should be "active". It come from the activeClassName="active" of the NavLink. If you check your 'react-router-dom' files you can see that. Eventually it will help you to reinstall 'react-router-dom'

Comment: I reinstalled 'react-router-dom'. No change. I've also updated Node.js same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I've been solved this problem when i uninstall the package **gh-pages** and reinstall

Comment: Oh really? I'll try that and get back to you. Is it part of react-bootstrap? Sorry for the late reply by the way.

Answer (score 0):

`a.active` doesn't applicable for Router NavLink's `activeClassName`. You have to refer to an existent style class `.active`, not `a`.
Remove the `a`:

```
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**React Router v6:**

Source: [Active NavLink Classes with React Router](https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/active-navlink-inline-styles-with-react-router)

Use the `className` property which now accepts a function and passes an `isActive` boolean property, like this:

```
<NavLink
  to="users"
  className={({ isActive }) => (isActive ? 'active' : 'inactive')}
>
  Users
</NavLink>
```

You can also adding multiple classes too, since **v6** is out:

```
<NavLink
  to="users"
  className={({ isActive }) =>
    isActive ? 'bg-green-500 font-bold' : 'bg-red-500 font-thin'
  }
>
  Users
</NavLink>
```

Check out the live demo: [Active NavLink Classes with React Router](https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/active-navlink-inline-styles-with-react-router)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Css Modules, if so then this is is what you're looking for; https://stackoverflow.com/a/60983995/12118813

Comment: @BarryMichaelDoyle erm I think it does if s/he is using css modules. I faced same problem and couldn't resolve it for hours till that SO answer drew my attention to it. It never occurred to me.